# calculating availability of node using SysUpTime.0 variable collcted in prometheus and exposing to grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, snmp, availability

I  am newbie to prometheus and grafana. In Prometheus I have  SysUptime.0 values from all my network nodes.
Now, I am trying to write formula in Grafana which will calculate node availability over time using SysUptime.0 snmp variable vaule ,which is collected  through snmp_exporter in Prometheus.
I tried to use rate function but doesn't work because SysUptime.0 is not counter type ,it is timeticks.
is there any way how can i do that?

thx in advance for your answers!
BR,
Marijana

I tried to use rate function but doesn't work because SysUptime.0 is not counter type ,it is timeticks.

Comment: Can you show an example of the metric containing value in question, and explain a bit more what that value supposed to mean?

Comment: The sysUpTime OID (Object Identifier) is a crucial part of the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP). Let’s dive into the details:

OID: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3
Description: The sysUpTime represents the time (in hundredths of a second) since the network management portion of the system was last re-initialized. In other words, it tracks how long the system has been up and running since its last restart or initialization.
Syntax: TimeTicks (measured in hundredths of a second).

Comment: rate(ipnet_sysUpTime{job="pe_routers"}[$__rate_interval])

Comment: and ever time i test formula i ve got different  result and for different  number of devices ( i only change display time)

Comment: So basically `ipnet_sysUpTime` contains timestamp of the last power-on?